# Unity: onEditEnd and onSubmit only firing from Return key

Tags: unity, input, gui, events

I have an `InputField` in my UI, but currently I can only submit its contents via the Return key. I tried mapping other buttons to the Submit action (e.g. the tab key on keyboard and the X button on my joystick), but neither worked. I tested both `onEndEdit` and `onSubmit` (via the Event Trigger component).

That said, `onClick` is being called correctly when I remap my Submit button. I can navigate the menu with my joystick and alternate keyboard controls, but I can't submit the `InputField` without pressing Return. Why is this?